# Multiple regexp replace in string

Tags: regex, elisp

I made a function that prompts me for values of variables (formatted `%^{var1}`) it found in a string and fills in said values.

```lisp
(defun fill-var-in-string (STRING)
  "Find variables in a string, prompt for a value and fill in STRING."
  (let ((filled STRING))
    (while (string-match "%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" STRING (match-end 0))
      (setq filled (replace-regexp-in-string (format "%%^{%s}" (match-string 1 STRING))
                                             (read-string (format "%s: " (match-string 1 STRING)))
                                             filled)))
    filled))


(message "filled in: %s" (fill-var-in-string "(%^{size}, %^{center})"))
```

It works, I'm wondering if I did it the lisp way. I did not make it `interactive` since for now I only will call this programmatically in `org-mode` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style-wise, it looks odd to see the function argument named in all-caps.  Standard convention is to use lower-case (but still upcase it in the doc-string).

---

Trying to run the code, it immediately failed:

```
Lisp error: (args-out-of-range "(%^{size}, %^{center})" 455)
  string-match("%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" "(%^{size}, %^{center})" 455)
  (while (string-match "%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" STRING (match-end 0)) (setq filled (replace-regexp-in-string (format "%%^{%s}" (match-string 1 STRING)) (read-string (format "%s: " (match-string 1 STRING))) filled)))
  (let ((filled STRING)) (while (string-match "%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" STRING (match-end 0)) (setq filled (replace-regexp-in-string (format "%%^{%s}" (match-string 1 STRING)) (read-string (format "%s: " (match-string 1 STRING))) filled))) filled)
  fill-var-in-string("(%^{size}, %^{center})")
```

This is clearly becase `(match-end 0)` could have *any* value at entry.  I think we need another variable (`start-pos`):

```
(defun fill-var-in-string (string)
  "Find variables in a string, prompt for a value and fill in STRING."
  (let ((filled string)
        (start-pos 0))
    (while (string-match "%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" string start-pos)
      (setq filled (replace-regexp-in-string (format "%%^{%s}" (match-string 1 string))
                                             (read-string (format "%s: " (match-string 1 string)))
                                             filled)
            start-pos (match-end 0)))
    filled))
```

---

We can simplify a little, because `(format "%%^{%s}" (match-string 1 string))` is exactly what we just found, so we can replace all that with `(match-string 0 string)`:

```
(defun fill-var-in-string (string)
  "Find variables in a string, prompt for a value and fill in STRING."
  (let ((filled string)
        (start-pos 0))
    (while (string-match "%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" string start-pos)
      (setq filled (replace-regexp-in-string (match-string 0 string)
                                             (read-string (format "%s: " (match-string 1 string)))
                                             filled)
            start-pos (match-end 0)))
    filled))
```

---

I'm not convinced that we should be matching an empty name - I would use `+` rather than `*` in the regular expression there.

---

There's a subtle failure case.  If the user provides a string that matches a replacement format, then it might get subsequently filled in (if it's a replacement we have yet to process).  To avoid this, we shouldn't start replacing until we have read all the replacement strings - we'll need to populate an alist mapping variables to values, and then go through the string performing the replacements as a second phase.

Comment: Cheers mate. Thanks for the suggestions. Sorry that it failed the first time. I tested it before posting here but I guess the `(match-string)` still had some info in it. As for the naming convention, in most of the Emacs code I go through, the parameters are all ALLCAPS. Granted this is in the `*help*` buffer, this is why I used ALLCAPS. I clicked now further and checked the source code and there it's lowercaps. Will use the lowercase convention for now on.